# How do I remove lines from a file and move them to another file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Ok so the file contains:

```
apple,bot,cheese,-999
tea,fire,water,1
water,mountain,care,-999
```

So I want to check if the lines in file 1 have a -999 at the end and if they do, remove that line, and transfer the one that does not into a new file. So far my function has:

```
def clean(filename,cleanfile,value,position):
filename.readline()
for line in filename:
    if line[position] != value:
        cleanfile.write(line)
```

Value is -999 and position is 3. I opened my files in my main and passed them to the function, the problem is that the new file is empty.

Comment: line is a string.  `line[position]` is a single character. (Assuming 'filename' is actually an open file rather than a filename.)

Comment: -999 isn't at index 3. Do your really mean "at the end" or do you want to break the line into columns and pick which column to use as a filter?

Comment: I want it to be a column would i split at the commas and do it?

Comment: You should look into the csv module: it splits each line into a list, then you can compare the last item in that list with '-999'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
def clean(filename,cleanfile,value,position):
    for lines in filename.readlines():
        line = lines.strip().split(",")
        if line[position] != value:
            cleanfile.write(",".join(line) + "\n")

clean(open("readFrom.txt", "r"), open("writeTo.txt", "w"), "-999", 3)
```

Comment: Ok i tried yours it does the opposite it deletes everything except for the ones ending in -999, i want the -999 ending ones deleted leaving the rest

Comment: Ok i fixed it, i made == to !=

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `csv` module to figure out the details of splitting and joining the comma-separated values.

```
import csv
def clean(filename,cleanfile,value,position):
    with open(filename) as reader_fp, open(cleanfile, 'w') as writer_fp:
        reader = csv.reader(reader_fp)
        writer = csv.writer(writer_fp)        
        for row in reader:
            if row[position] != value:
                writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: Do i have to use csv?, is there another method without using csv?

Comment: you can read the lines and split on the commas yourself. csv just handles the little details, that's all.

Comment: @user3373402 Why wouldn't you want to use `csv`?

Answer (score 0):

if you know that the value is always at the end of each line, you can try :

```
def clean (file1, file2, value):
    for line in file1 :
        if line.strip().split(",")[-1] != value :
            file2.write(line)
    file1.close()
    file2.close()

clean(open("readFrom.txt", "r"), open("writeTo.txt", "w"), "-999")
```